# Rails, Paperclip, Valum's Ajax Uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, file-upload

I'm new to Rails and I'm following the below post to combine valum's ajax uploader with paperclip. The uploader appears to work, as the images post to the database and the 'system' directory that paperclip creates.  But the uploader returns a "failed" message every time.  The error is generated from fileuploader.js, but I don't know why.  Aside from the fileuploader.js, I'm using this code which was copied from the below blog post.  I'm sure I should provide more information to receive an effective answer, so please let me know what I can provide.

Thank you

http://mooooooooooo.wordpress.com/2010/12/03/paperclip-valums%E2%80%99s-file-uploader-and-middleware-continued/

```
$(function() {
  function createUploader(){
    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
      element: $('#file-uploader')[0],
      action: '/photos',
      multiple: false,
      allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']
    });
  }
```

createUploader();
});

I should also mention that I am using firebug and I the "get" and "post" functions appear to work properly, with no errors there.

Here is the code from the controller, but I don't think the error message is coming from here, since the message doesn't include "failed"

```
def create
  @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
  if @photo.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created photo."
    redirect_to photo_path(@photo)
  else
     flash[:error] = "Post Error"
      redirect_to new_photo_path
  end
end
```

Here is the view code as well:

```
  <%= content_for :head do %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "fileuploader" %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "picture_drag_drop" %>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "fileuploader" %>
<% end %>

<h1>Photos#new</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/photos/new.html.erb</p>


<%= form_for @photo, :html =>{:multipart=>true} do |f| %>
<%= f.label :title %>
<%= f.file_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
 </div>
<% end %>

<div id="file-uploader">
    <p>Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You may provide the particular code of your controller (create action I guess) and your view (_form ?),

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering, I figured this out.  I just needed to change the error message in the view to: "render :text => '{"success": true}', :content_type => "application/json"

But I think having to post all the code forced to look at it a little harder, which may have helped.  I hope nobody wasted too much time bothering to read this!  My apologies.

Comment: You may write an answer and accept it yourself. Someone may have similar problem and your question and your solution will help him. That's how StackOverflow works. And welcome! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I just had to change the controller code to:

```
def create
 @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
 if @photo.save
 render :text => '{"success": true}', :content_type => "application/json"
```

I'm not completely sure why this worked, but I'm assuming the original "if" response couldn't show because the page didn't refresh and the 'render' text is outputting the "success" message from fileuploader.js.  Either way, it worked!

Comment: Was the photo correctly saved with this method? Or did you just save the name of the file?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem in an ASP.NET implementation. Valum's file uploader will show the user "Failed" unless your server side script that receives the file(s) outputs

```
{success:true}
```

My script was outputting "ok" because I didn't know it had to match the example code that comes with the library.